# Do we need the [standards] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The tag [standards](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standards) came up (currently only 3 questions).

I think we don’t need it.

It’s not an attribute/feature of a software, not even a use case I guess, but only something merely related to a goal (but even then it’s not clear what it really means).

If the goal is testing for (technical) standards compliance, [validation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/validation) could be used, I guess.
If a software has to follow some standards, it should be sufficient to state it in the question.

Comment: I agree. The tag itself is too broad since there are countless standards which could be international, national, or corporate. I don't think it helps to narrow down the questions. However, standard compliance could be considered a software feature like how [this question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/23/6834) uses it. But the name `standards` is vague. Perhaps `standard-compliant` is better

Comment: Me too: "standards" is much too ambiguous. Are we talking about quality standards? Standard algorithms? Web standards? Standard procedures (like ITIL)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[standards](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standards) would be an appropriate tag for software related to standards in general, which is sufficiently rare that I don't expect any legitimate use for the tag any time soon. It is not an appropriate tag on any of the three questions that it has been created for:

- [C++ IDE for Windows with a rich feature set: Code completion, refactoring, etc](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23/standard-compliant-c-ide-with-rich-features-code-completion-refactoring-etc) — This is about complying to the C++ standard, so it needs the [c++](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag (why didn't it have it‽), but [standards](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standards) doesn't apply.
- [Website Performance Testing Tools](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14547/website-performance-testing-tools) — the question mentions “performance standards”, as in performance goals, not as in standardization. The use of [standards](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standards) here is way out.
- [Is there free or open source software for checking PDF/A compliance?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18161/is-there-free-or-open-source-software-for-checking-pdf-a-compliance) — Like the C++ case above, this one is about complying to the PDF standard, so it should be tagged [pdf](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf) and not [standards](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standards).

Comment: So to sum up: `standard` can mean a bunch of different things, and thus is far too ambiguous to be used as tag. Yupp, agreed :)

Comment: @Izzy I think the answer means that it was supposed to stand for `standarization`. In which case it wouldn't be as ambiguous, but there aren't any questions that use it this way

Comment: Might be as well, true. But definitely, we don't need and don't want the `standards` tag, do we? :)

Comment: Gilles, as the tag "magically disappeared" (as a result of re-tagging, I guess) – can we count that as `status-completed` with a corresponding answer? :)